# Find vertex projection of one object on the vertex normal of another object

Tags: python, vertices, mathematics, vector

I have the following setup:

[image]

There are two objects: o1 (normal object; centered at the origin, no rotation) and o2 (it's a lattice; centered on a face of o1, rotated to match the rotation of the face). I want to move the vertex A (belongs to o1) to the normal of the vertex B (belongs to o2), represented by C in the picture.

So my reasoning is the following (everything is calculated in global space):

1. Calculate v1 by subtracting A.coordinates - B.coordinates
2. Calculate v2 by subtracting B.normal - B.coordinate
3. Project: v3 = v1.project(v2)
4. C = B.coordinates + v3
5. Transform coordinates of C from global space to the local space of o1.

The Python code that I have so far:

```
A: mathutils.Vector = ... (lattice point) obtain A in local space ...
B: bmesh.types.BMVert = ... (object vertex) obtain B in local space ...

o1_mw = o1.matrix_world
o2_mw = o2.matrix_world

v1: mathutils.Vector = (o1_mw @ A) - (o2_mw @ B.co.xyz)
v2: mathutils.Vector = (o2_mw @ B.normal) - (o2_mw @ B.co.xyz)
v3: mathutils.Vector = v1.project(v2)

C: mathutils.Vector = o1_mw.inverted() @ ((o2_mw @ B.co.xyz) + v3)
```

And it gives me some weird skewed results. Any hints to what might be wrong or another way to do this??

Thanks